# Sequelize special methods/mixins added to junction table instances

Tags: model, sequelize.js, associations, nodes

I have the following models setup in my app:

```
Model Team ->
               Junction Model GameTeam
Model Game ->
```

Thanks to this, I am able to use `special methods/mixins` like `game1.addTeam(team1)` etc. This is working as expected.

Next, I need to create another many to many association (including the junction table from above):

```
Model Player   ->
                  Junction Model PlayerGameTeam
Model GameTeam ->
```

Is it possible to use `special methods/mixins` as well, like this?:

```
const gameTeam1 = await game1.getTeams({
    where: {
        id: 1
    }
});

gameTeam1.addPlayer(player1)?
```

I am unable to make it work. The error I get:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: gameTeam1.addPlayer is not a function
```

The code I have:

```
Team.belongsToMany(Game, { through: GameTeam });
Game.belongsToMany(Team, { through: GameTeam });

Player.belongsToMany(GameTeam, { through: PlayerGameTeam });
GameTeam.belongsToMany(Player, { through: PlayerGameTeam });

...

const game1 = await Game.findOne({
      where: {
          id: 1
      }
  });

  const team1 = await Team.findOne({
      where: {
          id: 1
      }
    });

const player1 = await Player.findOne({
    where: {
        id: 1
    }
});

await game1.addTeam(team1);

const gameTeam1 = await game1.getTeams({
    where: {
        id: 1
    }
});

await gameTeam1.addPlayer(player1);
```

Thanks

Comment: I suppose `game1.getTeams` returns Team models and not GameTeam models

Comment: So, the only way is to do something like this ?:

const gameTeam1 = await GameTeam.findOne({
    where: {
        GameId: 1,
        TeamId: 1
    }
});

I this case I have to oparte on raw ids?

Comment: Or add an association like this: `Game.hasMany(GameTeam)`

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. I'll stick with passing raw ids. Thanks for help! @Anatoly